# IOS Build not vivible in Testflight Builds

Tags: ios, testflight

I have got builds in Activity log, and can upload them to the Apple Store, but I'd like to beta test first, with a few of my friends.
When I go to testflight, there are no builds vissible in my Version 1.1, while they are visible in Activity.

[image: What I see]

Hopefully anyone an explain why I can't see my builds in TestFlight.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did the build finish processing? It usually takes about half an hour or so, depending on size.

Comment: Yeah it did, even got an email saying it did. And I've even got a build from yesterday.

Comment: What browser are you using, can you check the console for any errors? Looks like a XMLHTTPRequest is failing or something

Comment: Currently using Chrome, should I try using another one?

Comment: Don't see any errors in console

Comment: If you go to Activity > All Builds, and click on the latest build, does it show any errors?

Comment: No, there are no errors visible. And the Appstore status says "Prepare for Submission". But I want to upload to Testflight and not AppleStore.